# How to write an algorithm that will delete observations on a specific condition?

Tags: stata

I have a variable `v1` with the following entries :

```
v1
1
2
4
11
13
5
6
7
```

How should I delete every observation that is repeated with a 1 in the front? In this case I want to delete 1 and 11, but not 13 because we dont have the corresponding 3 in `v1`.

```
describe v1

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
v1               int     %td
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Is your variable string or numeric? (If you don't know, show us the results of `describe v1`.)

Comment: Split the problem at hand into further smaller questions and google them. You will find your answer easily.

Comment: Thanks, but why has a daily date format been assigned here? What do the data mean?

Comment: v1 is just an example. The original numbers could also occur in date format.  But I am looking for a gerenal soultion than can be be applied to any variable with storage type : int

Comment: I think a general solution would follow from an explanation of what the operation means. It's not at all intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Given the incomplete information, here is something that seems to do what is requested. The two assertions confirm that the variable is of type int and that it is non-negative and either a single-digit or two digits of which the first is 1. Note that the statement of the problem does not specify what is to happen if there is, say, a 1 and two 11s: my interpretation is to delete every observation with the same final digit as long as there is a pair that qualify for deletion.

```
clear
input int v1
1
2
4
11
13
5
6
7
11
end
assert "`: type v1'"=="int"
assert inrange(v1,0,19)
generate digit = mod(v1,10)
generate hasone = (v1-digit)==10
bysort digit (hasone): drop if hasone[_N] & !hasone[1]
sort v1
list, clean noobs
```

which yields

```
v1   digit   hasone  
 2       2        0  
 4       4        0  
 5       5        0  
 6       6        0  
 7       7        0  
13       3        1
```